# Wiring a high voltage transformer

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer

[image]

So here is the image of the franceformer I purchased. I have no idea how to wire it like which one is voltage in, ground, all that. I cant find anything online for some reason. Also i see some transformers have a switch on the side like a button. What all does this button do, i saw a video where a guy puts the transformer in test mode with it but there must be more things. Please help!

[image]

Comment: There must be at least a model number on the part. Are there labels of any kind? Without a model number we cannot do more than guess, and we do not like to guess.

Comment: I uploaded the only image that came with it.

Comment: Looks like a $129.99 lesson in buying something without a datasheet. Sorry about it. You may be able to open it up and figure out what some of the connectors go to.

Comment: I think the bottom left where there is one screw is ground. And then where there is an oval looking thing the bottom screw is neutral and the top is hot. And im almost positive that either side of the top big porcelain parts can be positive or negative whatever you pick but idk and dont want to risk it.

Comment: You are really not qualified to be playing around with this if you can't even see that the terminals with the big ceramic insulators must be the secondary, and therefore, the other two terminals must be the primary. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Hah i know that the big ceramic ones are secondary thats what i said. I was saying i dont know which one is ground, neutral, and hot in terms of primary.

Comment: Heres the link to the listing https://m.ebay.com/itm/15-000-Volt-Neon-Transformer-30ma-Tesla-Coil-Jacobs-Ladder-No-GFI-/273024441267#vi__app-cvip-panel

Comment: where do we send the flowers for your funeral?

Comment: Jsotola i would rather have you send laser parts that i couldn't afford before my death like a ruby laser rod and a long coiled flash tube. Maybe some zink selenide lenses. Thank for the consideration. RIP

Comment: As the label states 15kv center tapped grounded (to frame), secondary 60ma (not 30ma). So total secondary voltage is 15kv between insulators, and 7.5kv from either output to the frame. To make a 15kv Jacob's ladder, electrodes need to be connected to each of the HV insulated outputs and kept clear of the frame (as either electrode would be 7.5kv to the frame and could arc).

Comment: I think you and I were in a bidding war over this transformer

Comment: Well bryan it was this transformer or a 150 dollar one that had a switch but idk if it could do jacobs ladder. This was my best option and seeing how these don't come up often at 15000 volts no GFI i had to get it no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big ceramic ones are the secondaries, obviously.

The "ground" terminal is (by definition) whichever terminal (if any?) is shorted to the metal enclosure. Use the continuity mode of a multimeter to check. If none of them are connected to the chassis, none of them are ground.

The neutral and hot are the remaining terminals. They should have low (but measurable) resistance between them, but infinite resistance to anything else.

If you think there's a difference between "neutral" and "hot" on a transformer, you probably shouldn't be playing with high-voltage transformers, or electricity in general.

Comment: My name is reese houseknecht, i live in pa. If you look up my name in about a week you might just find me dead. I am scared to use these transformers but i have to...

Comment: Ha! Can I offer a recommendation? Stick with the "one-handed rule" when working with anything high-voltage. If you don't touch a circuit with both hands, you're far less likely to electrocute yourself, as there's no current path through your heart. Wear shoes! Don't ground yourself! And above all, have fun :-)

Comment: Jay i see you subscribed haha. I actually upload a lot to the channel its just all unlisted. Heres a video link just about a capacitor tesseract im building. https://youtu.be/xjSzABhcQkA i send these to jarrod kinsey normally.

Comment: Jay - Hand to hand shock doesn't result in current flow across the ventricles. Hand to foot shock does, and is far more likely to cause ventricular fibrillation. The one hand rule only works if you and the equipment are well insulated from earth.